# How can you get coordinates of a country in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, react-native, maps

I am making a react native app which includes a map and want to place markers at the centres of different countries. However to create each marker you must provide a set of coordinates so I need a function to which I can pass a country name and it returns the coordinates for somewhere in that country (either of its centre or its capital would be good).

```
getCoords = (country_name) => {
    return coords {
        latitude: lat_of_country_centre
        longitude: long_of_country_centre
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a function or api that does this?

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see what and [ask]. HINT: Post effort and CODE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to use a geocoding API like [OpenCageData](https://opencagedata.com/api) to convert a country name into a country.

For example, using OpenCageData, the request `https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?key=YOUR_KEY&q=Germany` would return a JSON object which contains various information about that location name.

In this case, the coordinates would be located at the path in the JSON object `results[0].annotations.DMS`, which contains `lat` and `lng`, latitude and longitude coordinates in degrees, minutes, and seconds (e.g.) `51° 5' 0.31056'' N` for latitude and `10° 25' 24.40884'' E` for longitude.

Experimentation with this API or others like it may help you find data that is the best for your specific application.

Comment: Great api.```results[0].geometry``` returns just the coordinates so is easier to use

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at the [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation). That’ll give you a good starting point.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

you can take data from google i.e lat and long coords.
and load to your spreadsheet and write a simple program and load this into the array.